# Realm v12.6.2 with React Native v0.73.5, getting link error in iOS build compile

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, realm, realm-js

While adding the latest Realm node module v12.6.2, there is a bug from iOS app, linking issue.
Please suggest the workaround / solution to this issue.

[Realm React Native iOS link error - Screenshot attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkdO1.png)

"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.73.6",
"@realm/react": "^0.6.2",
"realm": "^12.6.2",

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

"_objc_msgSend$allBundles", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::copy_bundled_realm_files() in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::copy_bundled_realm_files() in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)

  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::remove_realm_files_from_directory(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$stringByAppendingPathComponent:", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::copy_bundled_realm_files() in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)

  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::remove_realm_files_from_directory(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$enumeratorAtPath:", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::copy_bundled_realm_files() in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)

  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::remove_realm_files_from_directory(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::copy_bundled_realm_files() in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$userInfo", referenced from:

```
  error_description(NSError*) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$pathExtension", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::remove_realm_files_from_directory(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$isEqualToString:", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::remove_realm_files_from_directory(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$stringWithUTF8String:", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::ensure_directory_exists_for_file(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)

  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::copy_bundled_realm_files() in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)

  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::remove_realm_files_from_directory(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)

  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::remove_file(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$code", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::remove_file(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::ensure_directory_exists_for_file(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$objectForKeyedSubscript:", referenced from:

```
  error_description(NSError*) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$containsString:", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::copy_bundled_realm_files() in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$defaultManager", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::ensure_directory_exists_for_file(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)

  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::copy_bundled_realm_files() in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)

  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::remove_realm_files_from_directory(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)

  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::remove_file(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$stringByDeletingLastPathComponent", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::ensure_directory_exists_for_file(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$fileExistsAtPath:", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::ensure_directory_exists_for_file(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)

  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::copy_bundled_realm_files() in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$removeItemAtPath:error:", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::remove_realm_files_from_directory(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)

  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::remove_file(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$localizedDescription", referenced from:

```
  error_description(NSError*) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$objectAtIndexedSubscript:", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::default_realm_file_directory() in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$resourcePath", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::copy_bundled_realm_files() in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

"_objc_msgSend$UTF8String", referenced from:

```
  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::default_realm_file_directory() in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)

  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::ensure_directory_exists_for_file(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)

  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::copy_bundled_realm_files() in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)

  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::remove_realm_files_from_directory(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)

  realm::JsPlatformHelpers::remove_file(std::_1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::_1::allocator<char> > const&) in librealm-js-ios.a(platform.o)
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Welcome to SO. That looks like one of the install steps was overlooked. Also are you installing via CocoaPods? Perhaps the code is missing `import Realm from "realm";`? Is this app attached to Expo?